# Good program structure when updating values in databound object

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture

I'm writing a Winforms based tool and could use some guidance on the structure. The program communicates with a piece of hardware over serial, and shows a GUI to display values. Most values are either set from the pc, or read from the device. There are some which are set from the pc and then confirmed by the device.

[image: data flow diagram]

Currently I have an Model object with all the values the device can send or receive. It uses a PropertyChangedEvent with a databinding to show values on the Form. Additionally there is a encoder/decoder that listens on the event, which encodes changes and sends it to the serial port.

In the serial port receive function the message is decoded, and the correct value in the Model is updated. The problem I'm having is that this will cause another PropertyChangedEvent, which will send another serial message. I'm looking for a good way to replace that listener with something else? I'd like to maintain the databinding to the form, so that every form element doesn't need an event.

Most values are declared like this:

```cs
private bool _voltageVBatToggle;
public bool voltageVBatToggle
{
    get => _voltageVBatToggle;
    set
    {
        if (_voltageVBatToggle != value)
        {
            _voltageVBatToggle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should not trigger `OnPropertyChanged()` the second time because the value received via your decoder should be the same as the previous value set via the UI. You should start debugging here.